Analycity of $f*g$ with $f$ and $g$ smooth on $\mathbb{R}$ and analytic on $\mathbb{R}^*$
Posted also on MO with a bounty
Suppose that we have two real functions $f$ and $g$ both belonging to $\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ analytic on $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ but non-analytic at $x=0$. Is the convolution (assumed to be well defined) defined as:
$$(f*g)(x) = \int_\mathbb{R}f(x-z)g(z)dz$$
an analytic function ?
Otherwise, under which conditions the convolution is analytic ?
Examples of functions $f$ an $g$ can be $x\mapsto x^{-(1+\alpha)}e^{-1/x}1_{x>0}$ with $\alpha>0$.
Any references or solutions will be highly appreciated.
Thank you!
